# java classpath issues when starting Cooja

Tags: java, ant, classpath, package

I have to run the well-known java-based Cooja simulator, extended with some classes I've made,  under Ubuntu 12.04. In my java file I recall the jfreechart packages:

```
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYLineAndShapeRenderer;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection;
import org.jfree.ui.ApplicationFrame;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.ValueAxis;
```

I run the simulator with this command:
**$ ant run_bigmem**

and then some exceptions pop up:

```
compile:
[javac] Compiling 44 source files to /home/user/contiki_copy/tools/cooja/build
[javac] /home/user/contiki_copy/tools/cooja/java/se/sics/cooja/plugins/sixlowpan_metrics/Chart.java:7: error: package org.jfree.chart does not exist
[javac] import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
[javac]                       ^
[javac] /home/user/contiki_copy/tools/cooja/java/se/sics/cooja/plugins/sixlowpan_metrics/Chart.java:8: error: package org.jfree.chart does not exist
[javac] import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
[javac]                       ^
[javac] /home/user/contiki_copy/tools/cooja/java/se/sics/cooja/plugins/sixlowpan_metrics/Chart.java:9: error: package org.jfree.chart does not exist
[javac] import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;

 .
 .
 .
 and so on..
```

Then I've modified the file: **/home/user/.bashrc** and I've added the following lines:

```
export CLASSPATH=.:/home/user/contiki_copy/tools/cooja/lib/jfreechart-1.0.11.jar:/home/user/contiki_copy/tools/cooja/lib/jcommon-1.0.14.jar
```

Then, from the prompt, I enter:
**$ echo $CLASSPATH** to see if the environment variable has been entered properly and I get, in fact:

```
user@ubuntu:~/contiki_copy/tools/cooja$ echo $CLASSPATH 
.:/home/user/contiki_copy/tools/cooja/lib/jfreechart-1.0.11.jar:/home/user/contiki_copy/tools/cooja/lib/jcommon-1.0.14.jar
```

Despite all these efforts nothing has changed and I still get the error..dunno what to do, really, any ideas?

I guess the crucial part of the **build.xml** file is the following:

```
<target name="run_bigmem" depends="init, compile, jar, copy configs">
<java fork="yes" dir="${build}" classname="se.sics.cooja.GUI" maxmemory="1536m">
  <arg line="${args}"/>
  <env key="LD_LIBRARY_PATH" value="."/>
  <classpath>
<pathelement path="${build}"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/jdom.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/log4j.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/jsyntaxpane.jar"/>
<pathelement location="lib/jfreechart-1.0.11.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/jcommon-1.0.14.jar"/>
  </classpath>
</java>
```

I've all the jars in the directory: **/home/user/contiki_copy/tools/cooja/lib** and I'm running everything inside the directory: **/home/user/contiki_copy/tools/cooja**.

Comment: what does you build file look like?

Comment: there it is:  
  
[link](http://pastebin.com/WihbBMxX)

Comment: I've also try running this:  
  
`user@ubuntu:~/contiki_copy/tools/cooja$ ant -lib /home/user/contiki_copy/tools/cooja/lib/jcommon-1.0.14.jar -lib /home/user/contiki_copy/tools/cooja/lib/jfreechart-1.0.11.jar run_bigmem`

nothing has changed..

Answer (score 0):

You need to include all the relevant jars in your ant "compile" goal (like in the "runfree" goal).  most likely, you can share a common set of libs between the various goals.  pretty sure you can this with ant, but i'm not super-familiar with it myself.

Comment: could you explain yourself deeper, please? you mean by running something like this:

`user@ubuntu:~/contiki_copy/tools/cooja$ ant -lib /home/user/contiki_copy/tools/cooja/lib/jcommon-1.0.14.jar -lib /home/user/contiki_copy/tools/cooja/lib/jfreechart-1.0.11.jar run_bigmem` ?

Comment: @user1405417 - no, i mean, fix your build file.  if you are doing it on the commandline or in the shell env, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: @user1405417 - in the "run" goal, there is _no_ mention of the jfreechart jar.  maybe i'm missing something (not an ant expert), but how is that expected to work?

Comment: aaahn I got it now, I edited the post now..I'm using the "run_bigmem" goal actually as you can see now. As you see there are the two jars in tis scope.

Comment: @user1405417 - i guess i misspoke as well.  the error is in the _compile_ step.  that goal is where you are missing the relevant jars.  also, the "run_bigmem" goal doesn't have the jars either, only "runfree".

Comment: ye you're right with the "runfree", I forgot to update the link of the buil.xml file, now I'm looking at the right target..this is not solving my error tough..about the compile step..how should i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

**FINAL SOLUTION:**
The only way to fix this problem is through the build.xml file. It's clear that **ant doesn't care about the java classpath env-var**. When editing the build file, make sure you put the jars, you need for your project, in the right "goal" and even in the "compile" target of xml file.

For example, if you start cooja in this way:

```
ant run
```

you need to edit the goal "run" of the build file. If you start the simulator in this other way:

```
ant run_bigmem
```

you need to edit the "run_bigmem" goal.

In addition, **make sure to edit properly also the "compile" goal**, otherwise the compilation will fail and a lot of imports will fail as well.